# Is standing on a sidewalk with a sign that says "Slow down, Speed trap ahead" illegal?

Tags: united-states

Police set up a speed trap on a busy intersection. Bob decides to create a sign that says "Slow down, Speed trap ahead" and get way ahead of the speed trap to slow people down. He is slowly walking up the sidewalk. Is Bob breaking the law?

Comment: I've seen decisions come out both ways over the years in news reports.

Comment: Vic.Australia had a case where a person was warning people that they were over the speed limit. Police prosecuted, but court held (on the facts) that intention to defeat speed trap was not proved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe there are courts that have affirmed convictions for obstructing official business or something along those lines, but the general consensus seems to be that conduct like this is not a crime, or that it cannot be criminalized without violating the First Amendment.

The most recent decision on point came just a few weeks ago. In [*Friend v. Gasparino*, No. 20-3644 (2d Cir. Feb. 27, 2023)](https://casetext.com/case/friend-v-gasparino), a man sued police for arresting him because he had set up a sign saying "Cops Ahead" two blocks away from where they were running an operation to enforce distracted-driving laws. The trial court dismissed the case, holding (1) that the sign was not protected by the First Amendment because it was "of little, if any, public concern"; and (2) that even if it was protected, the officer's conduct in arresting him satisfied strict scrutiny because if police wanted to prevent distracted driving, there was no less restrictive alternative to arresting the plaintiff.

But the Second Circuit reversed, holding (1) that speech remains protected even if it is not a matter of public concern; and (2) that there was no evidence that limiting the plaintiff's speech was *necessary* to permit the state to write citations and enforce the law, even if it would have been helpful.

Comment: Bedsides, not every distracted driver would notice the sign, because distracted drivers are, well, distracted.

Comment: Ha. This seems like a fact that should have figured more prominently in the strict-scrutiny analysis.

Answer (score 1):

[switzerland](/questions/tagged/switzerland)

Most likely, Bob is breaking the law. In Switzerland, the use of radar detection devices is illegal, as is the public distribution of information about speed cameras. This includes creating public groups on social media platforms such as WhatsApp or Facebook to warn speeders of these traps. So I'm assuming putting up a sign that warns people is illegal, too.

In Switzerland, the possible sentences for speeding can be very high, up to several years in jail. The possible sentences for warning about speed traps are [equally high](https://www.bussgeldrechner.org/radarwarner-schweiz.html) (but of course, the sentence will depend on the reach of one's announcement, so Bob is probably just given a fine, as opposed to when he would be distributing his information on some broadcast channel).

Comment: The speeding penalties in Switzerland are rather low, however. If the maximum speed is exceeded by a relatively small amount.

Comment: @phoog Compared to Germany or Austria, even "small" fines are quite significant.

Comment: The smallest fine for speeding on the motorway is 20 francs.  I can't believe that the corresponding fine in Germany or Austria is significantly lower.

Comment: @phoog That's where it starts out equal, but the difference rises quickly. [Motorway in Switzerland](https://www.fedlex.admin.ch/eli/cc/2019/93/de): 1-5 km/h 20Fr, 6-10 km/h 60, 11-15 km/h 120, 16-20 km/h 180, 21-25 km/h 260, more than that: Criminal charge. [Motorway in Germany](https://bussgeldkatalog.geblitzt.de/bussgeldkatalog/geschwindigkeitsverstoss/geschwindigkeitsueberschreitung/): 1-10km/h 20€, 11-15km/h 40€, 16-20km/h 60€, 21-25 km/h  100€, 26-30 km/h 150€, etc.

Comment: In the UK, I believe it is quite location dependent. Do NOT go 71 mph on a motorway in Cornwall.

Answer (score -3):

Not even a little. It also doesn't matter what you call them. Legally speaking, in Washington a "speed trap" [is defined as](https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=46.61.470) "a particular section of or distance on any public highway, the length of which has been or is measured off or otherwise designated or determined, and the limits of which are within the vision of any officer or officers who calculate the speed of a vehicle passing through such speed trap by using the lapsed time during which such vehicle travels between the entrance and exit of such speed trap". Certain specific methods of speed-calculation are legal. However, an officer with a radar gun is not technically a speed trap, even if people talk about it that way.

Comment: Almost reads as if you are asking if the speed trap itself is legal, rather than whether the fact that someone is tipping people off about it is legal, which is what the question is asking.

Comment: This reminds me of some "math-related" jokes/puzzles about highway police ticketing someone for having travelled 60 miles, in a 60 mph zone, in just 50 minutes: they could not prove that the person was speeding at any particular time, but basic math (the so-called "mean-value theorem") does "prove" that at some point they had to be travelling at least 6/5 times 60 mph, which is 72, which is substantially over the limit, etc. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Probably a losing argument for the police. The ticket needs to specify which jurisdiction the speeding offense was committed in as that goes to the jurisdiction of the LEO and the court handling the ticket to enforce the traffic offense, and a 60 mile long stretch of highway is almost never all in one jurisdiction.

Comment: @ohwilleke aha! A very interesting practical-legal point! Thanks! :)

Comment: In the UK they have lots of speeding cameras that do "average speed" measurements: Take a photo at junction A, another photo at junction B, and then simple maths shows how fast you must have gone. Stops the very annoying behaviour of people slamming their brakes when they spot a camera, because it doesn't help.

Comment: @paulgarrett: When I first heard that legend, I was amused by the thought that the prosecutor would have to give a proof of the mean value theorem in court - but only beyond a reasonable doubt.

Comment: @ohwilleke: What if the ticket was given by the state police / highway patrol / etc, whose jurisdiction is presumably statewide?  Could the ticket just specify "Texas" or whatever?

Comment: @ohwilleke In germany, they have "average speed control areas" on some parts - they are remarked and several kilometers long. By getting in and out too fast with photos they can easily prove you must have sped by more than X, and ticket you - and so far these tickets are upheld.

Comment: "an officer with a radar gun is not technically a speed trap": Nowhere does the question mention radar.  Furthermore, the precise term used on the sign is not important to the question.

Comment: @NateEldredge I doubt basic arithmetic like that could come into question, but if it did I imagine the judge would encourage the parties to stipulate.

Comment: @ohwilleke but there are some counties that are big enough for that to happen. Furthermore, one could apply the same argument to someone who drove six miles in five minutes, a much easier thing to do within the boundaries of a single municipality.

Comment: @NateEldredge That would likely not matter. Even if the officer has jurisdiction across an entire state, the court in which the defendant is prosecuted likely does not. A court in El Paso isn't allowed to hear a case against a defendant charged with speeding in Dallas.

Comment: @Trish, gnasher: In both cases the jurisdictions are _much_ larger.  I'm not sure if it would be the Land or the entire Federal Republic in German, and in the UK it would _probably_ be "England" or "Scotland".